# Laravel with AngularJS Login

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

Im using Laravel 5 as an API and i have AngularJS running my frontend. 
I have built the login portion of the backend that accepts the form data and responds with a json object.

My question is when i recieve the success object from the api to say that the login details are sucessfull. How do i use AngularJS to then login the user from the frontend.

AuthenticateUser.php

> http://pastebin.com/PZqGCpz5

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.login = {};

    $scope.submitLoginForm = function () {

        var email    = $scope.login.email;
        var password = $scope.login.password;

        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '/api/1.0/auth/login',
            data    : { email, password },
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

JSON Response

```
success: Object
    message : authentication_successfull
    code    : 200
    user_id : 1
```

What steps should i take from here to log the user into the frontend.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of api_token approach.

First when you call a login api then create a unique token specific to user and save it database and send it in response as:

```
success: Object
   message : authentication_successfull
   code    : 200
   data : {api_token: some_random_key}
```

Then for subsequent request send that api_token in the request headers.
And server will automatically logins the user if you are using the `auth:api` middleware as:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() 
{
    // API routes here
});
```

For [reference](https://andrew.cool/blog/64/How-to-use-API-tokens-for-authentication-in-Laravel-5-2)

Comment: Thanks, i will give this a try